# Classpath в Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

В настройках идеи установлено, что папка sources (src по-умолчанию) входит в classpath.
На деле же, это не так. Кто-нибудь объяснит, почему в classpath входит лишь папка target/classes

Comment: чему это мешает?

Comment: @titov_andrei мне

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может, на деле только компилированные файлы(*.class*) должны в **classpath** быть?!

Comment: для чего тогда папка src в зависимостях проекта находится !?

Comment: @voipp, смотри на файл настройки модуля(<module_name>.iml), там `<output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/classes" />` для `<sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src isTestSource="false" />`

Comment: и ? что с этого?

Comment: `//$MODULE_DIR$/src ` компилируется в `//$MODULE_DIR$/target/classes` папку(там будет .class файлы)